# I have an issue on selections (outlines do not appear anymore)

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, interface, edit-mode, selection-tools

It has been a while I have been using Blender with little knowledge of it. I often use key shortcuts to get quicker in modeling, but it happens sometimes that I miss a letter or press a wrong letter instead, that creates some issues. Long time ago I had the problem by clicking "h", which was hiding the model and I couldn't figure out what I was doing.

This time I cannot see my selections anymore, whether in object/edit mode. Neither the full orange model outlines appear, nor the vertices.. So it is very uncomfortable to use. I may have triggered/toggled something relating to the view. I tried to restart Blender, but nothing changed.

If somebody knows what is it about, I'd be happy to get this problem solved! :)

Thank you

Comment: Can you still see the grid lines?

Comment: Does it change when starting a new project file?

Comment: So easy to solve indeed. I often use the shortcut "ctrl+Z" and other ones, so I missed a button or something. But this I'll definitely know once for all! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

click on this button "show overlays" - then it works like before.

[image]

[image]

Tip: never "try out" shortcuts if you don't know them. This prevents lot's of trouble :)